How to write a function that returns parent path in makefile
I am creating a new makefile and I would like to create a set of utility functions which may be repetitively called. One of the functions is about how to return the parent path from any given path, e.g., return /some_folder from /some_folder/somefile. I can use subst and last word to extract the last word from the path. But I don't have a clue on how to exclude the last word. I would also like to find the common ancestor of two paths. Is there a general solution to such problems in makefile?

Did you also try the dir function, which extracts the directory-part of a given pathname?  In general, don't use text-processing functions on pathnames.

and: "repetitively calling functions" sounds a lot like you're trying to integrate the build system configuration step in your makefile. That's fine – a lot of smaller projects do that to find one or two libraries – but note that basically all larger projects abhor from doing to much in Makefiles; it's just hard to maintain, in my humble opinion. Instead, people use autoconfigure, cmake, meson, … to set up their build system.

I don't think you can do that using make-expansions, but it is relatively easy to do in shell (if your shell is ksh or bash):
$ mypath="/a/b/c/d"
$ echo ${mypath%/*}
/a/b/c

The expansion cuts off everything including and after the last "/" character and returns the rest. You can similarily extract the filename too. Notice that the value of the variable is NOT changed by that.
$ filename="/a/b/c/d.ext"
$ print - "${filename%/*}"
/a/b/c
$ print - "${filename##*/}"
d.ext
$ print - "${filename}"
/a/b/c/d.ext


Parent directory
parent1 = $(dir ${1:/=})
parent2 = $(if ${1:/=},$(dir ${1:/=},/)

parent1 works except for the cases of . and /. The former can be avoided by calling abspath. parent2 is a fix for the / case if it is needed. The function uses the shorthand patsubst to remove a trailing /, as the dir function only removes characters after the last /. Use in a Makefile like this
parent = $(dir ${1:/=})
p1 = /home/icarus/file
p2 = /home/icarus/dir/
all: ; @echo Parents of ${p1}, ${p2} are $(call parent,${p1}) $(call parent,${p2})

Common Ancestor
Makefile example
common-ancestor = $(if $(find string //${1},//${2}),${1},\
                  $(call common-ancestor,$(dir ${1:/=}),${2}))
p1 = /abc/src/baa.c
p2 = /abc/obj/baa.o
ancestor = $(call common-ancestor,$(abspath ${p1}),$(abspath ${p2}))
all:;@echo Ancestor of ${p2} and ${p2} is ${ancestor}

Essentially add a prefix of // onto each string to anchor it, look for one string in the other. If found return the shorter string, otherwise go up a directory level and repeat (using recursion). Can use the parent1 function as we don't need to worry about / as it would already have been found to be the common ancestor. Function is inlined as it is shorter that way.
